# Is there a JMESPath Terminal for windows 10?

Tags: python, windows, pip, installation, jmespath

I have installed python 3.5.2 on my windows 10 machine. I also installed JMESPath Terminal by using following command on windows command line:

pip install jmespath-terminal

Everything went smooth and it was successfully installed.

But when I type following:
jpterm

It says that 'jpterm' is not recognized.

Am I missing something or that above pip command only works on non-windows machines only?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: this is currently (dec 2017) simply not supported on Windows.

The install is broken. You can get `jpterm.py` from the project's GitHub page [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jmespath/jmespath.terminal/master/jpterm.py) and pop it into your `\pythonXX\Scripts\` folder.

Then you'll get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\Scripts\jpterm.py", line 239, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Python36\Scripts\jpterm.py", line 228, in main
    screen = urwid.raw_display.Screen()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python36\Scripts\jpterm.py", line 239, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "C:\Python36\Scripts\jpterm.py", line 228, in main
screen = urwid.raw_display.Screen()
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\urwid\raw_display.py", line 85, in __init__
fcntl.fcntl(self._resize_pipe_rd, fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)
NameError: name 'fcntl' is not defined\raw_display.py", line 85, in __init__
    fcntl.fcntl(self._resize_pipe_rd, fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)
**NameError: name 'fcntl' is not defined**
```

...and looking it up in the `urwid` project issues (the thing that draws "windows" in the terminal), you'll get this:

https://github.com/urwid/urwid/issues/152

which basically says 'urwid doesn't support Windows'.